# Error in rendering partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am rendering ajax request for action where i am expecting to receive a partial view.
instead i am getting full rendered page including layout page and i am not sure why

my action:

```
 public PartialViewResult Menu(int? caseId)
    {
        if (caseId != null)
        {
            ViewBag.MenuId = caseId;
        }
        return PartialView("_MenuPartial", null);
    }
```

My view is rendered using jquery ajax

```
  function loadMenu(id) {
                $.ajax({
                    data: "/Home/Menu?caseId=" + id,
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                        $("#menucontainer").html(data);
                    }
                });
            }
```

and finally my view is which is named "_MenuPartial":

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
    @if (@ViewBag.MenuId == 1 || @ViewBag.MenuId == 2)
    {
        <li>link @ViewBag.MenuId</li>
    }
</ul>
```

Any idea why its returning full page instead a partial view?

Comment: Where/how are you calling this `loadMenu` javascript function?

Comment: Can you do `@ViewBag` like that? You sure your "full page" isn't an error page...?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen: Yes you can. The page is just rendered full page including layout.

Comment: @cpoDesign: Actually I was wondering about the extraneous `@`s inside the if - I thought you could only use the "not a C# keyword" @ before actual keywords. Seems you can use them anywhere.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen: as far as i understand it, this is just saying from here starts c# code. and this will work everywhere

Comment: @cpoDesign: Not that `@`, the one inside the if, not before. Those are two different `@`s. The two `@`s inside the if are the verbatim prefix: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670(v=vs.71).aspx and I forgot that you can use them for non-keyword identifiers as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your .ajax() call looks a bit off.  You should be using the "url" property to call your controller action.  It would look something like this:

```
function loadMenu(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/Menu?caseId=" + id,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#menucontainer").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Assuming all of your files are in the correct folders, you should get the results you are expecting.  If you need to pass a more complex data type to your action, you could serialize a JSON object and send that in the data parameter.